# How to add limit in ticket tool | Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am creating ticket tool for my bot, but a user can create unlimited ticket seamlessly but I want that a user cannot create more than 1 ticket. I have no idea how to do this your help would be really appreciated

```
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
if payload.member.id != bot.user.id and str(payload.emoji)== u"\U0001F3AB":
    msg_id, channel_id, category_id= bot.ticket_configs[payload.guild_id]

    if payload.message_id == msg_id:
        guild= bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)

        for category in guild.categories:
            if category.id == category_id:
                break

        channel = guild.get_channel(channel_id)

        ticket_num= 1 if len(category.channels) == 0 else int(category.channels[-1].name.split("-")[1]) + 1
        ticket_channel= await category.create_text_channel(f"Ticket {ticket_num}", topic= f"Channel for ticket number {ticket_num}.", permission_synced= True)

        await ticket_channel.set_permissions(payload.member, read_messages= True, send_messages= True) 

        message= await channel.fetch_message(msg_id)
        await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, payload.member)

        await ticket_channel.send(f"{payload.member.mention} Thank You! for creating this ticket staff will contact you soon. Type **-close** to close the ticket.")

        try:
            await bot.wait_for("message", check=lambda m: m.channel== ticket_channel and m.author== payload.member and m.content == "-close", timeout= 3600)
        
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ticket_channel.delete()

        else:
            await ticket_channel.delete()
```

Comment: You could create channels with the name of the author and then check if already one channel with this name exists.

Comment: do not use the authors name in the channel name (maybe emotes or some special character cant be in channel name), I prefer to use the authors id in the channel description, sinze it is unique

Comment: Then use that to denote if someone already made a ticket, another way would be to use a database (or a file)

Comment: Better save the channel's id in the db. That's what I would do.